# Convergence radius, power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series

How can I determine the convergence radius of the following power series:

$F(n,z):=\sum_{j=0}^nz^{3j^2}+5z^{j^3}$ ?

I've tried with the formulas

$ r=\frac{1}{\limsup_{n \to \infty} \sqrt{|a_n|}} $ and $r = \lim_{n \to \infty} |\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}|$ but hadn't any success yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you mean the series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^{3j^2}+5z^{j^3}$, then:

- since it diverges when $z=1$, the radius of convergence is *at most* $1$;
- since each series $\sum_{j=0}^\infty z^{3j^2}$ and $\sum_{j=0}^\infty5z^{j^3}$ converges when $\lvert z\rvert<1$ (by the ratio test), the sum converges when $\lvert z\rvert<$ and therefore the radius of convergence is *at least* $1$.

So, the radius of convergence is equal to $1$.